# What is the system user Qt for?

Tags: support, chat

User -1 has always been [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1). It performs system actions on the main site. User -2 is [Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2). It posts system messages into the chat. And user -3 is [Qt](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-3/qt). It... wait, what?

Comment: ...implements cross-plaform UIs in weird-looking C++.

Comment: @Shog9 I rarely type "LOL" because I'm rarely laughing out loud. But this time: LOL

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Moderators have the ability to [create new system users](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=224930#224930) who behave as [Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2), but have a customized name and gravatar. Presumably that's what happened here, even though [Qt](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-3/qt) isn't a very talkative fellow.

On the other hand, Qt's distant cousin on chat.SE, [Lazers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-23/lazers), is much more vocal, despite being a little...slow.

Comment: There's also [Worst Questions Ever](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-29?tab=recent).