# How do you change Feeds' nickname?

Tags: support, chat, feed

I've seen over at the **[Anime and Manga chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga)** that *Feeds* take the form of *Hell Butterfly*.

How can I implement it on my own chat room? Is it even possible for regular users? Or is it a mod only power?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a moderator-only ability that involves [creating a new system user with a custom name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123577/what-is-the-system-user-qt-for) to take the role of the Feeds bot for some particular feeds.

Comment: I see! Is it possible to somewhere request it?

Comment: I don't think that there's any official process for (or necessarily any policy around) doing so, so your best bet is to just ping one of your site's moderators in chat to ask nicely and see what happens.