# Clearly demarcate custom feed users as such

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

Site mods can currently set feeds to automatically chat messages in their chat rooms. Additionally, they can create a special [feed user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123577/what-is-the-system-user-qt-for) specially for this purpose.

Since [these](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-25) [users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-26) have no parent site, no rep, negative user ids, and (usually) no information other than recent chat messages, users who know of these phantom accounts can easily identify them. However, users unfamiliar with this feature would be easily confused (I was). (Sometimes site mods may write an "about" explaining that the user is a bot, but this is usually not the case.)

Would it be possible to clearly indicate the nature of these users on their profile?

Comment: "Feed User" only appears if you're a moderator