# Why was the feeds user renamed to "Check for incoherent ramblings and crackpotism"?

Tags: discussion, chat, feed

I came across something rather bizarre today, when I noticed this:

[image: New message preview, by a user names "Check for incoherent ramblings and crackpotism"]

The cause being:

[image: Feeds user in chat but with a different name]

Upon further investigation, the [Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/check-for-incoherent-ramblings-and-crackpotism) user (ID -2) appears to have been renamed:

[image: Feeds user's chat account]

**Was this intentional? Why has the SE-wide feeds user been renamed?**

Comment: Note that a CGCC mod ([hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)) has now [renamed it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57737674#57737674) back to "Feeds"

Answer (score 21):

#### This was likely a moderator editing its display name.

Our (being myself and another mod on TL) best guess, unless someone explains themselves, is just that someone was trying to set up a feed in a chat and thought to change the display name of the feed, not realizing that it was a network-wide user and that that would change the display name everywhere.

I have changed it back. To any moderator reading this, please don't screw with its name. If you want your room's feeds to have a custom name, click the "create user" button after creating the feed [to create a new feeds user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123577/369802), so you can set an image and display name for it. Don't change the Feeds user (ID -2) itself because that goes across the network.

Comment: Ah, I remember doing this once before (years ago) - and we changed the avatar so we had to go digging for the default avatar to boot... good times.

Comment: @Catija oh haha, that's not good! doesn't sound like a lot of fun to have to go fix :P

Comment: According to Wayback Machine, it was still named Feeds on April 18, when it was last saved, so maybe that's when it was renamed.

Comment: @user We figured out who changed it and what went wrong :P was just a simple mistake, like earlier today probably